# Can't use a variable from an await mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, async-await

I'm having a problem using the mongodb query result on another query.
I hope this code explains it (it's written inside an async function) - Please notice that i'm using created_comment._id in the second query:

```
let created_comment = await Comment.create(new_comment, (err, newReturnedComment)=>{
if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }           
});

await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id},{ $addToSet: {commentsIds: created_comment._id} },
    function(err, updated_user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

so even though i'm using await in the first query, when i try to access the created_comment variable i'm not getting anything. is it because create and findOneAndUpdate are not promises? Can you please refer me to a guide that explains whats the best way to make such queries on a nodejs backend?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass a callback to mongodb functions if you want to use `async`/`await` and expect the calls to return promises. Just write

```
try {
    const created_comment = await Comment.create(new_comment);
    const updated_user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$addToSet: {commentsIds: created_comment._id}});
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: thank you! it really helped me. so my mistake was using the callbacks?

Comment: Yes, IIRC mongodb methods don't return promises when you pass callback arguments. Also callbacks are pretty useless with `await`…